# How to round output rectangles of SquarifiedTreemap algorithm so they can fit a grid with every tile being 1x1

Tags: algorithms, rectangles

This can be trivial but nonetheless I need help... :)

I have a grid, every tile of the grid is 1x1. I'm using SquarifiedTreemap algorithm to divide the grid in rooms, but the result values are in floating point whereas I need integer values.

I've tried to round the values of the rectangles to the nearest integer, but results are inconsistent, sometime one rectangle overlap another, some other time there's a gap between two rectangles.

Here's an example with a grid 20x10, ratios are [30, 28, 15].

```
regular: (x:0.00, y:0.00, width:8.41, height:10.00)
rounded: (0, 0, 8, 10)

regular: (x:8.41, y:0.00, width:7.25, height:10.00)
rounded: (8, 0, 7, 10)

regular: (x:15.65, y:0.00, width:4.35, height:10.00)
rounded: (16, 0, 4, 10)
```

As you can see, the total area of the grid is 200, but the total area of rounded rectangles is 190. In fact, in my grid there's a 1x10 gap between two rectangles.

Thank you.

Comment: What is "SquarifiedTreemap" algorithm and what is it doing on a grid with undistinguishable squares ? How can we imagine what are the "rooms" if you don't define them ? Your question is likely to be closed because it is not understandable.

Comment: Sorry about that, Squarified Treemap is an algorithm that divides a rectangle into many little rectangles, according to the values passed as input. In the example above, the main rectangle is 20x10 size, the values are [30, 28, 15], that can be taken as ratios between them.

Comment: It is always good to give (thorough) references like [this one](https://www.win.tue.nl/~vanwijk/stm.pdf)

Comment: That's right, I didn't think about it. :)